# How do I put a background image on the body in css with django using static?

Tags: python, html, django, static, collectstatic

How do I put a background image on the body in css with django using static?

Is it something like this? I can't find any information on this. Thanks.

```
{% load static %}
body {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-image: url("{% static "assets/images/2.gif" %}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative path. Relative to the folder where the css file reside.

```
background: url('../assets/images/2.gif');
```

And use it in template file like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'css_file_address' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```